# How do I resignFirstResponder when I click outside of a UITextField onto a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield, first-responder

I am having trouble getting the keyboard in my iPhone app to go away because the `UIView` even when made a controller is not touchable because of the fact that I have a `UITableView` taking up the rest of the available screen.

I was curious to know how I would go resigning the keyboard aka `firstResponder` by clicking onto the `UITableView`? Is there a way to monitor a touch event on the `UITableView` even if it is not to select a clickable cell.

Basically, I know how to resign the keyboard if the cell fires the event but, if I click on a non - clickable part of the `UITableView` I would still like the keyboard to go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 options:

- In your viewController, respond to the table's scroll callback and resign the responder

> ```
> -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
> {
>      [self.view endEditing:YES];
> }
> ```

- You can always add a **UITapGestureRecognizer** to the table/view and resign the responder from there

Personally I usually do it on table scroll, since I don't like a single tap to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you the UITapGestureRecognizer did exactly what I needed it to do. I appreciate the time. I am sure the scroll works as well, I just needed the tap in this case but will keep the scroll in my inventory for later.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a tap gesture recognizer is an interesting solution, but there's an alternative and you don't need to code anything!

You can set in Interface Builder the property *keyboardDismissMode* to "Dismiss on drag" for your table view. It's a property inherited from UIScrollView and whenever you scroll your table view, the keyboard is dismissed.

Answer (score 3):

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = 
            [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
             initWithTarget:self 
             action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
            doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
            [doubleTap release];

    }

 - (IBAction)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender 
 {
    CGPoint p = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];

   if(indexPath == nil)
   {
     NSLog(@"empty");
   }
   else
   {
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
 }
```

I think it will help... try it..

Comment: I ended up using the scroll because when I put a tapgesture on the tableview it cause the cells to no longer read taps and thus the cells would not submit the cells because the tap gesture was eating up the event. Thank you though and I will probably need this code in another situation down the road.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *activeTextField; // keeps track of whose keyboard is being displayed.

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   self.activeTextField = textField;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // if (indexPath equal to something then)
   [self.activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```