# dismiss iPhone keyPad in dynamic UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have `UITableView` with two sections. First section is a static row with stepper which creates cells of second section. Each cell of second section contains the `UITextField` with keypad. I can dismiss the keypad using `UITapGestureRecognizer` or additional DONE button in keypad but it is working for the last cell only.
I have tried the following methods:

1. `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the table view

in my `ViewDidLoad` I put:

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

and then

```
-(void)hideKeyboard{
    [self.tableView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

or

```
-(void)hideKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{
    [self.cellText endEditing:YES];
}
```

1. Use tags to recognize which textfield I am editing.

In

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath I added
    [cellText addTarget:self action:@selector(myNumberValueBeginEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

and in

```
-(void)myNumberValueBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    int row = [sender.superview.superview tag];
    UITextField *cellTemp = (UITextField*)[(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview viewWithTag:200+row];
    cellTemp.delegate = self;
    [cellTemp becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

then I am trying to resignFirstResponder in DONE button

```
-(IBAction)doneButton:(UITextField *)sender {
NSLog(@"doneButton");
    int row = [sender.superview.superview tag];
    [(UITextField*)[(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview viewWithTag:200+row] resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I have no more ideas how to resign the keypad from all `UITextFields`. If anyone has some remedy, I will really appreciate.

Comment: this answer may help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063798/iphone-tableview-with-textfields-next-previous-button-issue/15064918#15064918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your use of `endEditing:`. Instead of sending `endEditing:` to an instance of your text field, try sending it to your main view. e.x:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

`endEditing:` can be sent directly to a text field instance, or to a view, in the case of the latter any text field that is editing that is a subview of the view you specified will resign first responder.

From the docs:

> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the
>   first responder status

Comment: Thanks a lot. Almost in the same time I found out the answer too in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503172/how-do-i-resignfirstresponder-when-i-click-outside-of-a-uitextfield-onto-a-uitab)